# https urls on subdomain redirect back to main domain url

Tags: security, redirect, https, dns

I have a subdomain, dev.domain.com. If I try to access https://dev.domain.com it redirects back to domain.com. I do NOT want secure urls to redirect back to the main domain. I believe this is controlled by a simple .htaccess rule but I don't know where to start. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can do this by the .htaccess. 
best way to start ist [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (apache mod_rewrite)

You could check your .htaccess and also your apache configuration where you already do the forwarding and change it.